# How to deploy a updated functionality in a workflow through farm solution

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2013

I have a visual studio workflow running on a list. Now the requirement is to update a particular functionality on this workflow. However, if I do a retract/deploy on the solution, details of all previous workflow instances will be lost - as in, if I wanted to look at an individual item's workflow history, I will not be able to find it in workflow menu under the item.

Is there any process to retain the details of existing workflow while deploying new functionalities to it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use PowerShell command, not Visual Studio Deploy action. By default it retracts solutions and installs it again.

Rebuild your project and publish it to a ".wsp" file. Then open SharePoint Management Shell and type:

```
Update-SPSolution -GACDeployment -LiteralPath <path to your published project>\<project name>.wsp -Identity <project name>.wsp
```

But if you insist on using Visual Studio in whole process, there is a nice add-on that covers it: [CKS-Dev](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cf1225b4-aa83-4282-b4c6-34feec8fc5ec).

Comment: No, of course I don't insist on using Visual Studio. Actually I was trying update through UI for my sandbox solution, which I couldn't find any way of doing. So, let me try powershell now with a farm solution. Whatever works for now.

Comment: Sorry, eventually I got the time to test this. It seems the update-spsolution does not delete the old association, however it doesn't update the workflow either, i.e. my workflow continues running on the old flow, and anything new I have added doesn't trigger. I have already tried feature deactivate/activate, which didn't work. Anything I might be missing?